# Insert даты в базу данных

Tags: python, pymysql

Я пытаюсь добавить спаршенные с помощью RSS результаты  в таблицу моей БД.
Получаю такую ошибку, когда пытаюсь сделать **insert** даты в таблицу:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2019-09-18 05:21:18+00:00' for column 'item_datetime' at row 1")

Собственно вот скриншот столбца таблицы в которую я делаю **insert**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот участок кода отвечающий за **insert** данных:

```
 sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`, `item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link), str(rss_title), str(rss_datetime), str(rss_description)))
```

В `rss_datetime` хранится дата в таком формате **`2019-09-18 05:21:18+00:00`** может ли быть ошибка, из-за того что в дате присутствуют лишние символы такие как **`"+00:00"`**  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как говорилось в ответе выше это была не корректная дата для mysql.

Решил эту ошибку  так:

Перед тем как отдавать дату `dateparser` для преобразования даты.Удалил лишние элементы **"+00:00"** 
Таким образом:

```
rss_published = feed.published
                if len(rss_published.split(" ")) > 5:
                    data = " ".join(rss_published.split(" ")[:5])
                    rss_datetime = dateparser.parse(data) # 2019-09-18 06:20:55
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего да. Посмотрите как должен выглядеть [datetime в mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Формат отображения такой `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` в диапазоне от
`'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` до `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`.
Если хотите указать микросекунды, то пишите в таком формате от
`'1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000'` до `'9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'`.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за уточнение!